# Magento 1.5 Shopping Cart Is Not Persisting Items

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

We are working on a Magento-based website that sells outdoor gear.  We have discovered an issue in which the shopping cart is expiring in 30 minutes to 2 hours when it should be persistent for 30 days or until the customer places their order.

See http://www.usadventurer.com/

To reproduce the issue, simply try the following:

1. Add any item to your cart
2. Refresh the cart or visit any other page and verify that the shopping cart still has your item
3. Wait 30 minutes to 2 hours, refresh and your shopping cart will be empty.

The site configuration is as follows:

Magento 1.5.0.1

In .htaccess:

php_value session.cookie_lifetime 2592000

In Magento Admin Panel

System > Configuration > General > General - Locale Options:

Timezone is set to same as server (US Eastern Standard Time)

System > Configuration > General > Web - Session Cookie Management:

Cookie Lifetime is set to 2592000

System > Configuration > Sales > Checkout - Shoping Cart:

Quote Lifetime (days) is set to 30

We aren't sure what is causing this problem as the settings look good (though I think we shouldn't have to increase the session lifetime.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: and have you verified that your php ini allows to override this value?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to increase the session timeout to 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

That can't be the right answer you already said you did that in both Web - Session Cookie and Checkout - Shopping Cart.

Was flushing cache the trick?